# Show file names based on what is selected in drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to get a value from a select box and use it for a PHP function further down on the page.

I have index.php with a regular select drop down. The value and option in the select box is the name of a folder. When I pick a folder, I want to get that value through jquery/ajax without updating the entire page. I'm then going to use that value in another php function further down on the page where I list the file names found in that folder.

I also have a script.js file. What I have so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select-folder").change(function() {
     // Get selected value and send to index.php
  });
});
```

I'm new to jquery and ajax so I don't quite know how to send this value without updating the entire page or if it's even possible? Perhaps I need to include the javascript as a script tag on the index.php page?

## Updated to add new code

This is in my index.php file and works to get the folder name to send it to file.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#select-folder").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
    url: "/files.php",
    data: "site=" + value,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(var1, var2) {
      console.log(var1 + var2);
    }
    })
  });
});
</script>
```

Then, in file.php I get the folder name and loop through all the files inside the folder.
But when I output with this code:

```
echo '<p>' . $file . '</p>';
```

It outputs in the console log and not in the index.php

## Problem solved

I realized after a lot of searching that I should add the code into a div through ajax or it wouldn't show up because of page loads.

I added this piece of code to the success part of the javascript from above:

```
$('#show-files').html(var1);
```

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.  I think what you're trying to say is you're going to do DOM manipulation to change just part of the page based on what the value of a drop down menu?  And the source of that change will come from a PHP script that is sent that drop down menu data?

Comment: I want to change part of the page based on the value of a drop down, yes. And, yes, the value from the drop down data will be added to a PHP function that finds files within a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example.
We have next folder (tree) structure:

```
./images
  |--/foto1
  |---- 1-1.jpg
  |---- 1-2.jpg
  |---- -13.jpg
  |--/foto2
  |---- 2-1.jpg
  |---- 2-2.jpg
  |---- 2-3.jpg
./index.php
```

Select index/foto1 folder in you *select* element with value "images/foto1"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select-folder").change(function() {
        var folderName = $(this).val(); // get a folder to display.
        $.ajax(
            url: "index.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'folder':folderName},
            dataType: "json"
            success: function(data){
                 console && console.log(data);
                 // data variable will contains array of files
                 $("#result").html('');
                 for(i=0,c=data.length;i<c;i++)
                     $("#result").append(  data[i]+'<br>');
            }
        );

    });
});
```

index.php contains next code:

```
<?php
$files = array();
if( isset($_POST['folder']) && file_exists($_POST['folder']) && is_dir($_POST['folder']) ){
   if ($handle = opendir($_POST['folder'])) {
       while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
           array_push($files, $entry);
   }
}
echo json_encode($files);
```

Also you need to add security check for input (directory check).
You can use for this [realpath()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php), [dirname()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) and other [Filesystem functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

Comment: Thank you for your response. This was closest to how I eventually solved it, so I'll mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('/index.php', { selectedId: this.value }, function(resultHTML){
    $('#containerId').html(resultHTML);
});
```

This code sends selected value to `index.php` page which returns part of html and we put this part somewhere on page (in this case in element with id containerId)

Comment: When I use the code it creates a duplicate of everything on my index.php 
I've tried using it both within my own code that I wrote above and outside of it.

Comment: You want to call a PHP file that only outputs the part of the page you want.  The two ways of doing it are making it a separate file, or including some code in your index.php script to only output the whole page if it's not being called from the $.post.  I don't know the layout of your page, so I can't really recommend one way or the other.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I have changed my code so now it sends an ajax request to another php file Files.php. In files.php, I get the folder name, loop through all the files in that folder. And it works well, but when I write `echo '<p>' . $file . '</p>' ` it will only output this in the console log. How do I get it to display on my index.php page? Do I need to do more Ajax functions?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I edited my original post to show the new code I have.